# Database for storing Ontology models/Flexible hierarchy structures

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, nosql, relational-database

I am designing a system for a scientific collaboration website. Basically, there are many different data models for different research topics. The columns, field types, number of columns,mappings and structures are different. Each existing data model can also be reused by other people.

The scenario example: 
a scientist comes in and design an experiment type A, then the data model gets created and he starts to filling data in. The data model of Experiment type A is then saved, can be reused, other people can choose this model A and filling in data without redesigning. Similarly, scientists can design whatever data models they like.

For example:

Experiment type A we have structure:

```
-Hypothesis(String target1,String target2, int number1,int number2)
  -existingwork(String target1,string target2) //(maps to Hypothesis table) 
-Cohorts (int number1,int number2)
  -male //(maps to Cohorts table) 
  -female //(maps to Cohorts table) 
-Results (String result1,String result2)
```

Experiment type B we have structure:

```
-Hypothesis(BigInt bigint,String name,String target)
  -feedback(String feedback) //(maps to Hypothesis table) 
  -comments(String comment,Date date) //(maps to Hypothesis table) 
-ExperimentTarget (int number1,int number2,int number3)
  -Healthy //(maps to Cohorts table) 
  -Unhealthy //(maps to Cohorts table) 
-Impact (int impackFactor)
-Conclusion(String conclusion,Date date)
```

What would be the optimal method of implementing this? If we create a schema for each experiment type, I think it would be too heavy, isn't it?

I have thought about Nosql approach, but it looks like the mapping part is hard(e.g. mapping "existingwork" to "Hypothesis" in type A).

How about some graph database such as http://neo4j.org/, can this do the job?

Guys, please advice! Thanks

Comment: Can you consider XML? Each investigation could have its own XML schema, and there's lots of good infrastructure software for handling and displaying it.  When you get around to handling large quantities of XML data, you'll find quite a few DBMS solutions that do an OK job.

Comment: @Ollie Jones For XML, its difficult to search and manipulate, isnt it:?

Comment: XML is easily searchable with a well worked out search language called XQuery, based on a document-matching scheme called XPath.  Its syntax is a little arcane but it works. There are plenty of implementations of this language, both commercial and open-source.